# django-jenkins - AttributeError: 'Coverage' object has no attribute '_harvest_data'

Tags: python, linux, django, jenkins, code-coverage

I have installed django-jenkins in following environment

```
coverage (4.0.1)
Django (1.8)
pep8 (1.6.2)
django-jenkins (0.17.0)
pyflakes (1.0.0)
```

and I when I try this

```
python manage.py jenkins --enable-coverage
```

I get this error

```
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Storing coverage info...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_jenkins/management/commands/jenkins.py", line 161, in handle
    coverage.save(tested_locations, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_jenkins/tasks/with_coverage.py", line 33, in save
    self.coverage.stop()
AttributeError: 'Coverage' object has no attribute '_harvest_data'
```

Any ideas ? I followed [this](https://sites.google.com/site/kmmbvnr/home/django-jenkins-tutorial) manual exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the django-jenkins uses Coverage and in newest version of coverage the method _harvest_data has changed to get_data but in the final official release of django-jenkins it has not been applied so I switched to their latest git version and it solved.